# install windows PE 1.5 to a USB/hard drive

Tags: installation, windows-pe

I have been using a tool called Bart's PE builder which creates windows PE 1.5 boot images, however I need to make some adjustments - so it it cant be installed on a CD which is read only.

I cannot seem to figure out how to to this. I have tried a tool called PEtoUSB but it won't detect any USB devices on windows 10/XP. I tried powerISO but nor virtual box or real hardware can boot from the USB stick despite following the guide on how to boot from USB on virtualbox.

Is there a way PE 1.5 can be installed on either a Hard drive or USB stick? My only option right now is a batch script 'PE2USB.BAT' that came with Bart's PE builder but its fiddly.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to use Windows tools to create a bootable PE USB:

- Download latest [Windows 10 ADK](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/get-started/adk-install) (Assessment and Deployment Kit)
- Install only the components *Deployment Tools* and *Windows Preinstallation Environment*
- Open an elevated *Deployment and Imaging Tools* by right clicking it in
  *Start > Windows Kits > Run as administrator*
- Enter the command `cd\` to shorten the displayed path
- Create WinPE files with following command :

  ```
  copype amd64 D:\WinPEx64
  ```

Replace path `D:\WinPEx64` with your preferred drive and folder name. The above command creates PE files to be used to boot a 64 bit machine. For 32 bit, replace `amd64` with `x86`.

- If the USB flash drive is `I:` enter the following command:

  ```
  MakeWinPEMedia /UFD D:\WinPEx64 I:
  ```

For more information see the article
[Create a WinPE USB or ISO](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/103428-create-winpe-usb-iso.html).

---

For Windows PE 1.5 itself, it was only available for selected OEM
and via Enterprise Software Assurance, so is not generally available
in a legal manner.

See [Windows PE Version Overview](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33619.windows-pe-version-overview.aspx) for versions.

You might be able to extract it from either:

- [Windows Automated Installation Kit (AIK) for Windows XP SP2](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10333)
- [WinPE 3.0 from Windows AIK 2.0](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=5753).

Comment: I'll give this a try, Does this work for windows PE 1.5 (based on windows XP), the windows 10 ADK will most likley be for PE10 (based on windows 10)

Comment: Windows PE 1.5 is too old and build from Windows XP since 2004. Not sure it would compatibility well with Windows 10. but why not use the latest Windows 10 ADK to create a new Windows PE tool? It would be the most security and safe measure which will not cost too much time.

Comment: @joy because its too big, is harder to customise, doesn't have the same command set that I need, etc.

Comment: I added what is available without searching for illegal downloads.

Comment: @harrymc the vista AIK you linked to does not have any program called MakeWinPEMedia. I have searched the entire computer including all removable drives.

Comment: You might be able to use the newer programs you have with the older files. It's pretty hard to go that far back and recreate a product that was not publicly available.